# Is there a modern (eg NoSQL) web analytics solution based on log files?

Tags: apache2, analytics, logging, static-content, apache-log-files

I have been using **Awstats** for many years to process my log files.  But I am missing many possibilities (like cross-domain reports) and I hate being stuck with extra fields I created years ago.  Anyway, I am not going to continue to use this script.

Is there a modern apache logs analytics solution based on modern storage technologies like NoSQL or at least somehow ready to cope with large datasets efficiently?

I am primarily looking for something that generates nice sortable and searchable outputs with the focus on web analytics, before having to write my own frontends.  (so **graylog2** is not an option)

This question is purely about log file based solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splunk can import Apache logs
http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/4.3.2/Data/Apachelogslocal

Or review this answer on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4772046/804087)

> A relatively recent option is to [use Flume to collect the logs](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2010/09/using-flume-to-collect-apache-2-web-server-logs/)
>   and [use the MongoDB sink plugin for Flume](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/tree/master/flume_plugin) to write the events to
>   MongoDB.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I will upvote it, as soon as I have gained the required reputation.  I will check it out, but depending on how Splunk calculates the indexing volume, the 500MB/day of the free version will not be sufficient and the pricing seems rather steep for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else comes along this problem:
My solution for the moment was to use [Goaccess](http://goaccess.prosoftcorp.com/) on the log files or on subsets using `cat` and `grep`.  It may seem as a regression compared to awstats or any software with some result storage, but its performance is great for ad-hoc log file analysis.